# PHP get $list to display each value in seperate columns

Tags: php, foreach, xhtml, html-table

What I need to do is get the values in $list to display in separate columns and for the titles of the columns to be inside the table on its own row.

```
   if (isset($_POST['check_list'][0])) {
    // form was submitted, checkbox was checked
     ?>
     <table>
     <table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Composer</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Album</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <?php
    foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $item) {
        echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>'; // here we add the table row and fill there all data from    $getColumn array, each one has own table cell
    }
    echo '</table>';
  } else if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     // form was submitted, checkbox wasn't checked
    echo 'Form was submitted and checked wasn\'t checked';
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

database page:

```
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox1" value="'. $getColumn[1].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox2" value="'. $getColumn[2].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox3" value="'. $getColumn[3].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox4" value="'. $getColumn[4].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox5" value="'. $getColumn[5].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox6" value="'. $getColumn[6].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox7" value="'. $getColumn[7].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox8" value="'. $getColumn[8].'" />';
    print '<input type="hidden" name="checkbox8" value="'. $getColumn[9].'" />';
    print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"value="'. $getColumn[0].'"</td>';
```

connection:

```
  $conn = pg_connect("host=**** port=****
  dbname=teaching user=csguest password=****);

    $res = pg_query ($conn, "SELECT ref, artist, composer, genre, title, album, label, price,  description FROM music");
    print "<table border='1'>";
    print "<th>Check box</th><th>Artist</th><th>Composer</th><th>Genre</th><th>Title</th><th>Album</th><th>Label</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
    while($getColumn = pg_fetch_row($res))
```

Comment: what/where is ur problem/question?

Comment: the data is not displaying correctly in a xhtml table :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, regarding your comments below I prepare you example with PHP and HTML too.

You can try to send the form. If you check the checkbox, table with values is rendered, in the other case you receve message that checkbox wasn't checked. It's just for you to understand how it works.

```
<?php

// this array you have rendered and filled elsewhere, it's just for this exaple
$getColumn = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j');

if (isset($_POST['check_list'][0])) {
    // form was submitted, checkbox was checked
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Composer</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Album</th>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Last one</th><!-- in your question you have only these 8 THs, in form you have 9 values. In this case it's just to have the same THs and TDs -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
<?php
        foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $item) {
            echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>'; // here we add the table row and fill there all data from $getColumn array, each one has own table cell
        }
    echo '</table>';
} else if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // form was submitted, checkbox wasn't checked
    echo 'Form was submitted and checked wasn\'t checked';
}

// and the simply form for testing
echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[0]" value="' . $getColumn[0] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[1]" value="' . $getColumn[1] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[2]" value="' . $getColumn[2] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[3]" value="' . $getColumn[3] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[4]" value="' . $getColumn[4] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[5]" value="' . $getColumn[5] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[6]" value="' . $getColumn[6] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[7]" value="' . $getColumn[7] . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check_list[8]" value="' . $getColumn[8] . '">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: okay i updated mine and its not displaying but no errors basically when checkbox echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[0]" value="' . $getColumn[0] . '">'; is ticked all the hidden ones need to tick too so it submits all the elements. When i do print_r($_POST); it only displays the last row of the table.

Comment: it only works with all the values in one checkbox so i'm keeping it  that way just trying to get it to seperate with explode is hard because i get an error saying its an array not a string